# unable to make one column in css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a survey form project from freecodecamp.org and when the viewport width < 768px I want the css grid to have only one column, but for some strange reason this doesn't happen.

my code

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700");
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background-color: #21a6ff;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: white;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

label {
  justify-self: end;
}

.input-field {
  justfy-self: start;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
}

select {
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #21a6ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.submit-btn {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  justify-self: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
  form {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">Developer Survey</h1>
  <p id="description">Let us know you more</p>
</header>

<form id="survey-form" method="POST" action="https://crossorigin.me/https://freecodecamp.com">
  <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>

  <label for="email" id="email-label">Email</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>

  <label for="number" id="number-label">Age</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="number" id="number" min="1" max="110" placeholder="Enter your age" required>

  <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown-label">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
  <select class="input-field" name="drop" id="dropdown">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="student">student</option>
    <option value="graduate">graduate</option>
    <option value="full-time-job">full time job</option>
    <option value="perfer-not-to-say">perefer not to say</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>

  <label for="radios" id="radios-label">do you love javascript?</label>
  <div class="input-field" id="radios">
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Definitely</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> maybe</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3"> not sure</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <label for="checks" id="checks-label">programming languages that you use</label>
  <div class="input-field" id="checks">
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"> Python</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2"> js</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3"> Java</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4"> C++</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="5"> C</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="6"> Lisp</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="7"> Other</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <label for="more" id="more-label">Any additonal comments?</label>
  <textarea class="input-field" name="more" id="more" style="height:50px;resize:vertical;"></textarea>

  <div class="submit-btn">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the property applied to the button `grid-column: 1 / 3;` forcing your grid to always be 2 columns at least.

You need to change this inside the media query:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700");
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background-color: #21a6ff;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  color: white;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

label {
  justify-self: end;
}

.input-field {
  justfy-self: start;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
}

select {
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #21a6ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.submit-btn {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  justify-self: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
  form {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .submit-btn {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">Developer Survey</h1>
  <p id="description">Let us know you more</p>
</header>

<form id="survey-form" method="POST" action="https://crossorigin.me/https://freecodecamp.com">
  <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>

  <label for="email" id="email-label">Email</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>

  <label for="number" id="number-label">Age</label>
  <input class="input-field" type="number" id="number" min="1" max="110" placeholder="Enter your age" required>

  <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown-label">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
  <select class="input-field" name="drop" id="dropdown">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="student">student</option>
    <option value="graduate">graduate</option>
    <option value="full-time-job">full time job</option>
    <option value="perfer-not-to-say">perefer not to say</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>

  <label for="radios" id="radios-label">do you love javascript?</label>
  <div class="input-field" id="radios">
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Definitely</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> maybe</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3"> not sure</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <label for="checks" id="checks-label">programming languages that you use</label>
  <div class="input-field" id="checks">
    <ul>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"> Python</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2"> js</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3"> Java</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4"> C++</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="5"> C</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="6"> Lisp</label></li>
      <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="7"> Other</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <label for="more" id="more-label">Any additonal comments?</label>
  <textarea class="input-field" name="more" id="more" style="height:50px;resize:vertical;"></textarea>

  <div class="submit-btn">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

> The grid-template-rows, grid-template-columns, and grid-template-areas properties define **a fixed number of tracks that form the explicit grid**. When grid items are positioned **outside of these bounds**, the grid container generates **implicit grid tracks** by adding implicit grid lines to the grid. These lines together with the explicit grid form the implicit grid.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#implicit-grids)</sup>

A simplified example to better illustrate:

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:50px; /*we explicitly define one column*/
  grid-gap:5px;
}
.box > div:first-child {
  grid-column:1/7; /*this will implicitly create more*/
  background:red;
  height:20px;
}
.box > div {
  background:blue;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

For more details:

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#explicit-grids

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#implicit-grids